# Finding integer roots of an integer quadratic form

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, quadratic-forms, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $ Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n ] $ be an integer quadratic form. That is, $ Q $ is a homogeneous degree $ 2 $ polynomial with integer coefficients. Is there a good way to determine if $ Q $ has any integer roots (other than all $ 0 $)?

I don't know if this helps but in the example I'm thinking about there are about $ 20 $ variables and the coefficients are very small, $ < 10 $.

For context I have a set $ \mathcal{E} $ of 15 orthogonal matrices with integer entries and  I'm trying to find integer zeroes of the quadratic form $ Q $:
$$
 Q(x_{ij}):= \sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}}(\text{Tr}(EX))^2−\sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}}\text{Tr}(EXE^{−1}X) 
$$
where the variables I am solving for are the entries of the symmetric matrix $ X $, and $\text{Tr}$ is the trace.

I would even be satisfied if I could determine if $ Q $ has real roots. But integer roots are preferable.

Comment: with five or more variables, all you need is that the form be indefinite. Recommend Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms.

Comment: page 60, Lemma 2.7

Comment: oh, well. I have two programs I wrote in C++ for my own use. The first one  takes a symmetric integer matrix $M$ (for now I type in the rows, one at a time)  and diagonalizes it over the rationals.   That is, it produces a rational matrix $P$   with determinant $\pm 1$   such that $P^T MP = D$  is diagonal.  Guaranteed. This  always reveals whether the associated quadratic form is definite or not. Also, if the coefficients of $D$  are not too bad, one may  make a column  vector $v$  such that $v^T D v = 0.$   Then $Pv$  gives zero with $M$   as $v^T P^T MPv =0$

Comment: @WillJagy "one may make a column vector $v$ such that $v^TDv=0$" - That seems to be the hard part, in general. Diagonalizing is fairly straightforward.

Comment: But of course that straightforwardness is what makes it programmable. -- What was your second program @WillJagy?

Comment: It's a pick and choose version that stays within integers. Each time it asks if I want to switch two rows/columns. If I type no it asks for two row/column indices  and an integer constant. Call them indices $i,j,$  constant $k.$  it makes a matrix $R$  that is the identity except the single value $k$  at position $i,j.$  If I have reached symmetric matrix $M_n$  it makes $M_{n+1}  = R^T M_n R $  and shows the updated $M.$   With care, one may gather small (absolute value) diagonal elements in the upper left corner, perhaps without off diagonal elements for a while.

Comment: @mr_e_man  I put an answer showing both programs for a 6 by 6 symmetric matrix I made up.   The second program was very successful, after a few steps showed enough to quickly find a null vector for my matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
\newcommand\trans{^{\mathrm T}}
\newcommand\span{\mathrm{span}}
$You're looking for "isotropic elements of $Q$ in the module $\mathbb Z^n$". This is the same as finding roots over the vector space $\mathbb Q^n$ because if you have such a root $x$ then $ax \in \mathbb Z^n$ for some $a \in \mathbb Z$.

I will start with the real case because it is easier, and then explain what changes with $\mathbb Q$.

---

For *existence* of real roots you just have to check that $Q$ is not positive- or negative-definite.

To find real roots, you can diagonalize: form the *symmetric* matrix $M$ such that $x\trans Mx = Q(x)$ with $x = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\trans$ and diagonalize $M = V\trans DV$. If $e_i = (0,\dotsc,1,\dotsc,0)\trans$ with $1$ in the $i^\text{th}$ position (so that $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ forms the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$) then $f_i = V^Te_i$ is an *orthogonal* basis for $Q$. By construction $Q(f_i) = D_{ii}$. The *signature* $(p, q, r)$ of $Q$ is the number of $f_i$ such that $Q(f_i) > 0$, $Q(f_i) < 0$, and $Q(f_i) = 0$, respectively.

We could also start with a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and apply Gram-Schmidt, but there are edge cases to consider when $Q$ is not definite.

Let $a_1,\dotsc,a_p$ be those $f_i$ with $Q(f_i) > 0$, let $b_1,\dotsc,b_q$ those with $Q(f_i) < 0$, and $c_1,\dotsc,c_r$ those with $Q(f_i) = 0$. Also normalize $a_1,\dotsc,a_p$ so that $Q(a_i) = 1$ and normalize $b_1,\dotsc,b_q$ so that $Q(b_i) = -1$.

If $r \ne 0$ then all linear combinations of $c_1,\dotsc,c_r$ give a root of $Q$. These are called *radical vectors*. However, I can easily imagine you constructed $Q$ such that $r = 0$ and there are no radical vectors. From here on we assume $r = 0$.

From here, every vector $v$ is of the form
$$
  v = \alpha_1a_1 + \dotsb + \alpha_qa_p + \beta_1b_1 + \dotsb + \beta_qb_q
$$
and $v$ is isotopic iff
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^p\alpha_i^2 - \sum_{j=1}^q\beta_j^2 = 0.
$$
But we can say some more.

The quantity $w = \min\{p, q\}$ is precisely the *Witt index* of $Q$. This is the dimension of a maximal totally isotropic subspace, i.e. a subspace of maximal dimension where all vectors are isotropic and so roots of $Q$. If $w = 0$ then $q = 0$ or $p = 0$ and $Q$ is positive- or negative-definite and has no roots.

If $w \ne 0$, then we can construct two such maximal totally isotropic subspace $W, W'$ by pairing up basis vectors. Define $\nu_i = a_i + b_i$ and $\eta_i = a_i - b_i$ for (say) $i = 1,\dotsc,w$. Then $Q(\nu_i) = Q(\eta_i) = 0$ and we can take
$$
  W = \span\{\nu_1,\dotsc,\nu_w\},\quad W' = \span\{\eta_1,\dotsc,\eta_w\}.
$$
These subspaces are *complementary* in the sense that we can construct $W'$ knowing just $W$ and vice versa. The space $H = W \oplus W'$ is called a *hyperbolic subspace*. Finding more isotropic vectors in $H$ is easy; every vector $v \in H$ may be written
$$
  v = \alpha_1\nu_1 + \dotsb + \alpha_w\nu_w + \beta_1\eta_1 + \dotsb + \beta_w\eta_w
$$
where $\alpha_i, \beta_i \in \mathbb R$. If every pair $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ has $\alpha_i = 0$ or $\beta_i = 0$ then $v$ is isotropic; more generally $v$ is isotropic iff $\sum_i\alpha_i\beta_i = 0$.

If $p \ne q$ then we still have some $a_{w+1},\dotsc,a_p$ or $b_{w+1},\dotsc,b_q$ remaining. Let $m = \max\{p,q\}$ and call these $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_{m-w}$. These span a subspace $A = \span\{\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_{m-w}\}$ which is *anisotropic*, meaning there are no isotropic vectors. Any of $\xi_1,\dotsc,\xi_{m-q}$ can replace $a$ or $b$ (whichever is appropriate) in the construction of $W, W'$ to get other maximal totally isotropic subspaces.

Returning briefly to $r$ not necessarily $0$ and defining $R = \span\{c_1,\dotsc,c_r\}$, the decomposition
$$
  \mathbb R^n = A\oplus H\oplus R
$$
is called a *Witt decomposition* of $\mathbb R^n$, and the dimensions of each piece are invariants of $Q$.

To be clear, **not all** isotropic vectors lie in $W$ or $W'$, this is just a convenient way of constructing many of them.

---

When we consider $\mathbb Q^n$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$, much of this is the same. There are two potential difficulties I see:

1. Diagonalizing $M$ rationally. In this case it is probably best to apply Gram-Schmidt or another orthogonalization algorithm, but I don't have much knowledge of this.
2. The vectors $f_i$ cannot be normalized unless $Q(f_i)$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb Q$. My construction of totally isotropic subspaces requires that $Q(a_i) = -Q(b_i)$, and there's no way to achieve this unless there is $\delta \in \mathbb Q$ such that $\delta^2Q(a_i) = -Q(b_i)$ whence we can replace $a_i$ with $\delta a_i$.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt: Take any basis vector $a\neq0$. If $Q(a)\neq0$, then project the other $n-1$ basis vectors away from $a$, and continue the process in that subspace. If $Q(a)=0$ and there's another basis vector $b$ not orthogonal to $a$, then project the other $n-2$ basis vectors away from the span of $a$ and $b$ (which is hyperbolic), and continue the process in that subspace. If $Q(a)=0$ and all other basis vectors are orthogonal to $a$, then nothing needs to be done in this step; continue the process in the span of the other basis vectors. -- These projection operations can be done rationally.

Comment: (And any hyperbolic plane produced in the process can be given an orthonormal basis, rationally. Given $\langle a,a\rangle=0\neq\langle b,a\rangle$, define $b'=\frac{b}{\langle b,a\rangle}-\frac{\langle b,b\rangle a}{2\langle b,a\rangle^2}$, so that $\langle b',b'\rangle=0$ and $\langle b',a\rangle=1$. Then take $c=a+\tfrac12b'$ and $d=a-\tfrac12b'$ as the new basis, with $\langle c,c\rangle=1=-\langle d,d\rangle$ and $\langle c,d\rangle=0$.)

Comment: What is an example of a quadratic form $ Q $ a Witt decomposition $ \mathbb{R}^n=A \oplus W \oplus W' \oplus R $ and a vector $ v $ such that $ v $ is isotropic but $ v \not \in W \oplus W' \oplus R $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Apologies, I noticed a lot of bad typos in my last comment, so I'm going to delete it and write it again.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be an orthogonal basis such that $Q(e_1)=Q(e_2)=1$ and $Q(e_3)=−1$. Then $$\mathbb R^3=⟨e1⟩⊕⟨e2,e3⟩$$ with $⟨⋅⟩$ meaning the span of those vectors is a Witt decomposition with $⟨e_2,e_3⟩$ hyperbolic; we can write $$⟨e_2,e_3⟩=⟨e_2+e_3⟩⊕⟨e_2−e_3⟩$$ as a decomposition into complementary maximally isotropic subspaces. But $Q(e1+e3)=0$ and this vector is not in $⟨e_2,e_3⟩$.

Comment: So for a quadratic form of signature $ p,q,r $ is it always true that the variety $ Q(v)=0 $ can be expressed as a union of maximally isotropic subspaces? In other words, as a union of subspaces of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ of dimension $ r+\text{min}(p,q) $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Yes, every null vector lives in such a subspace, so the union of all of them will give you all null vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the same problem has finding rational because, if $x$ is a zero, so is $ax$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}^\times$.

If you want to have any non trivial zero, you must have a real zero.

You may compute the rank and the signature of your quadratic $Q$ (viewed as a rational quadratic form), and then decide.

More precisely:

Viewing $Q$ has a rational quadratic form, you can use Gauss reduction to write $Q=\sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i L_i^2$, where $L_1,\ldots,L_r$ are linearly independent $\mathbb{Q}$-linear forms, and $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Q}^\times$.

If $r<n$, then $\bigcap_i\ker(L_i)$ is non trivial, and contain a non zero rational vector, hence (multiplying by a suitable integer) an nonzero integer vector, and we are done.

So assume now that $r=n$.

At this point, $Q$ has a non trivial **real** zero if and only if $Q$ is indefinite, that is the $\alpha_i$'s do not all have the same sign (Keyword: signature of quadratic form).

Now you are in luck: if $n\geq 5$ and $Q$ is indefinite, then a difficult theorem of Hasse Minkowski says that $Q$ has a non trivial zero. However, it does not produce you a way to compute it.

Comment: hi, I got the full 36 by 36 matrix, the upper left 9 by 9 corner has some null vectors with small integer coefficients; I put as new answers.

Answer (score 1):

I made up a problem  ...  I typed in a bunch of nubers as a six by six matrix. Then I had gp-pari add it to its transpose, making a symmetric matrix with even numbers on the diagonal. Then I had my first program diagonalize  over the integers.

Maybe I will have the patience to get something with the other program, stick with integers and try for  fewer off-diagonal elements

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 37 }{ 53 }  &  -  \frac{ 73 }{ 53 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 36 }{ 59 }  &  \frac{ 20 }{ 59 }  &  -  \frac{ 42 }{ 59 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 315 }{ 79 }  &  -  \frac{ 1394 }{ 237 }  &  \frac{ 407 }{ 79 }  &  -  \frac{ 1399 }{ 474 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2161927 }{ 175346 }  &  \frac{ 3046161 }{ 175346 }  &  -  \frac{ 2849569 }{ 175346 }  &  \frac{ 912841 }{ 87673 }  &  -  \frac{ 341933 }{ 87673 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 9 & 11 & 6 & 6 & 8 \\ 
9 & 14 & 13 & 10 & 9 & 10 \\ 
11 & 13 & 8 & 8 & 15 & 15 \\ 
6 & 10 & 8 & 14 & 35 & 21 \\ 
6 & 9 & 15 & 35 & 240 & 733 \\ 
8 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 733 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 37 }{ 53 }  &  -  \frac{ 36 }{ 59 }  &  \frac{ 315 }{ 79 }  &  -  \frac{ 2161927 }{ 175346 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 73 }{ 53 }  &  \frac{ 20 }{ 59 }  &  -  \frac{ 1394 }{ 237 }  &  \frac{ 3046161 }{ 175346 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 42 }{ 59 }  &  \frac{ 407 }{ 79 }  &  -  \frac{ 2849569 }{ 175346 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1399 }{ 474 }  &  \frac{ 912841 }{ 87673 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 341933 }{ 87673 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 53 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 118 }{ 53 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 474 }{ 59 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 87673 }{ 474 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 485147265 }{ 175346 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 73 }{ 53 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 34 }{ 53 }  &  \frac{ 42 }{ 59 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 36 }{ 53 }  &  -  \frac{ 180 }{ 59 }  &  \frac{ 1399 }{ 474 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 &  \frac{ 52 }{ 53 }  &  -  \frac{ 361 }{ 118 }  &  \frac{ 521 }{ 474 }  &  \frac{ 341933 }{ 87673 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 53 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 118 }{ 53 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 474 }{ 59 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 87673 }{ 474 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 485147265 }{ 175346 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 73 }{ 53 }  &  \frac{ 34 }{ 53 }  &  \frac{ 36 }{ 53 }  &  \frac{ 52 }{ 53 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 42 }{ 59 }  &  -  \frac{ 180 }{ 59 }  &  -  \frac{ 361 }{ 118 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1399 }{ 474 }  &  \frac{ 521 }{ 474 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 341933 }{ 87673 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 9 & 11 & 6 & 6 & 8 \\ 
9 & 14 & 13 & 10 & 9 & 10 \\ 
11 & 13 & 8 & 8 & 15 & 15 \\ 
6 & 10 & 8 & 14 & 35 & 21 \\ 
6 & 9 & 15 & 35 & 240 & 733 \\ 
8 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 733 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Got to admit, with the fractions in $D,$   if I multiplied through by a common denominator it might take me a while to find a null vector, that is $v^TDv = 0$

This is better. One step at a time,   reached a nice ternary section

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 7 &  - 1 & 0 & 5 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
43 & 0 & 0 & 62 & 1 &  - 58 \\ 
 - 12 & 0 &  - 1 & 7 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 9 & 11 & 6 & 6 & 8 \\ 
9 & 14 & 13 & 10 & 9 & 10 \\ 
11 & 13 & 8 & 8 & 15 & 15 \\ 
6 & 10 & 8 & 14 & 35 & 21 \\ 
6 & 9 & 15 & 35 & 240 & 733 \\ 
8 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 733 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 &  - 3 &  - 1 &  - 7 & 43 &  - 12 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 5 & 62 & 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 58 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 & 0 &  - 57 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 12 & 1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 & 32 &  - 664 & 59 \\ 
0 &  - 57 & 0 &  - 664 &  - 40074 &  - 456 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 &  - 2 & 59 &  - 456 & 96 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
4 & 4 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
5 & 6 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 &  - 4 & 58 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1 & 0 &  - 57 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 12 & 1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 & 32 &  - 664 & 59 \\ 
0 &  - 57 & 0 &  - 664 &  - 40074 &  - 456 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 &  - 2 & 59 &  - 456 & 96 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
1 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 6 & 1 &  - 4 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 & 58 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrr} 
2 & 9 & 11 & 6 & 6 & 8 \\ 
9 & 14 & 13 & 10 & 9 & 10 \\ 
11 & 13 & 8 & 8 & 15 & 15 \\ 
6 & 10 & 8 & 14 & 35 & 21 \\ 
6 & 9 & 15 & 35 & 240 & 733 \\ 
8 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 733 & 42 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

This time the matrix I am still calling $D$  has a pleasant upper left corner, three by three, namely

$$
C = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0    \\ 
0 &  - 4 & 1  \\ 
0 & 1 & 12   \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Using familiar variables  and half the Hessian I have $c(x,y,z) = x^2 -2 y^2 + 6 z^2 + yz $  This is isotropic (indeed the $y,z$  binary is), there are infinitely many triples that give zero, with
$ x = 7u^2 + 7uv \; , \; \; \; y = 5u^2 + 4 uv + 2 v^2 \; , \; \; z = - u^2 + 2 uv + v^2.$  For example, taking $u=0$ and $v = 1$   gives us null vector $(0,3,-2)$   We extend this to column vector $w_1= (0,3,-2,0,0,0)^T$
Using this integer $P$   we form $w = P w_1 = (-7,0,0,5,0,-2)^T$   This should be a null vector for the original matrix $H.$    IT WORKS.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your programs? For context I have a set $ \mathcal{E} $ of 15 orthogonal matrices with integer entries and the quadratic form $ Q $ I'm trying to find integer zeroes of is $ Q(x_{ij}):= \sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}}|Tr(EX)|^2−\sum_{E \in \mathcal{E}}Tr(EXE^{−1}X) $
 where the variables I am solving for are the entries of the symmetric matrix $ X $. And $ Tr $ is trace.

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira  you have a department address, I sent the programs there.

Comment: Thanks so much I'll take a look!

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira  the algorithm for the first one is discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr   Eventually I made it give output in Latex, that took a good deal of extra time...cannot expect Latex to show four 21 by 21 matrices as one displayed line, so you may want to adjust the output  after trying some $n$ by $n$ examples for very small $n$

Answer (score 1):

Here $H$  is the upper left 9 by 9 corner of your 36 by 36 matrix. I did just invertible integer operations  and got only as far as displaying a zero on the diagonal of $P^THP $  And the same vector will work for the full 36 by 36 when padded with zeroes,

$$( 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$
when written as a a row

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$ $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
0 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$  $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$   $$
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 & 16 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
 - 72 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 24 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 48 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 48 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 120 & 8 & 16 &  - 8 \\ 
 - 28 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
72 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)  $$  $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 & 16 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
 - 72 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 24 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 48 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 48 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 120 & 8 & 16 &  - 8 \\ 
 - 28 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
72 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)   $$  $$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) $$  $$
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
0 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Answer (score 1):

showing more null vectors. Note how the outcome $D$ has four by four with all $0$ on the diagonal. The lower 5 by 5 is visibly indefinite, so it is guaranteed that at least one more diagonal zero can be arranged, using just variables $x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9$  and hence keeping the upper left four the same; Tartakowsky.  Hmmmm, checking. Tartakowsky's original theorem may have been slightly different. Anyway, the magic number is 5.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
0 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 48 & 48 & 72 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
48 & 0 & 72 & 48 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
48 & 72 & 0 & 48 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
72 & 48 & 48 & 0 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
 - 16 &  - 16 &  - 16 &  - 16 & 120 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
 - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 &  - 144 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 28 &  - 28 &  - 28 &  - 28 &  - 8 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 24 &  - 24 &  - 24 &  - 24 &  - 16 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 48 & 48 & 72 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
48 & 0 & 72 & 48 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
48 & 72 & 0 & 48 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
72 & 48 & 48 & 0 &  - 16 &  - 72 &  - 28 &  - 24 & 72 \\ 
 - 16 &  - 16 &  - 16 &  - 16 & 120 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
 - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 &  - 144 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 28 &  - 28 &  - 28 &  - 28 &  - 8 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 24 &  - 24 &  - 24 &  - 24 &  - 16 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
72 & 72 & 72 & 72 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 &  - 2 &  - 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 2 &  - 2 &  - 2 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr} 
120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 8 &  - 16 & 8 \\ 
0 &  - 144 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 &  - 72 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 96 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 96 &  - 24 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 48 &  - 24 &  - 96 &  - 48 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 72 &  - 24 &  - 48 &  - 48 &  - 96 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 140 &  - 20 & 6 \\ 
 - 16 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  - 20 &  - 20 & 8 \\ 
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 28 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

I wrote  a little program, here are the integer null vectors with absolute values bounded by $1$

```
1   -1   -1    0    0    1   -1   -1   -1
1   -1    0   -1    1    0   -1   -1   -1
1   -1    0    1   -1    0   -1   -1   -1
1   -1    1    0    0   -1   -1   -1   -1
1    0   -1   -1    0    0   -1   -1   -1
1    0   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1   -1
1    0   -1    0   -1    0   -1   -1   -1
1    0   -1    1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    0   -1    0   -1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    0    0   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    0    0    1    1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    0    1    0    1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    1    0    1    0   -1   -1   -1
1    0    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
1    0    1    1    0    0   -1   -1   -1
1    1   -1    0    0    1   -1   -1   -1
1    1    0   -1    1    0   -1   -1   -1
1    1    0    1   -1    0   -1   -1   -1
1    1    1    0    0   -1   -1   -1   -1
```